# How would I use libstdc++ with clang?

Tags: clang, libstdc++

I am wondering how I would use libstdc++ with the clang compiler.  I'm on a windows 7 machine for your information and have alredy installed libstdc++.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `-stdlib=libstdc++` to clang.

Example:  `clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ junk.cpp`